# wrappanel listbox item select event

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, listbox, wrappanel

I have used wrappanel and listbox to display my items on wp7. but item click event does not working. my code is as follow

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Height="Auto">
            <ListBox x:Name="lstDevice">
                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <toolkit:WrapPanel/>                        
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate >
                        <StackPanel>
                            <Button x:Name="btnData" >
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                    <Canvas 
                                            Width="175" 
                                            Height="175"/>                                            
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Width="175" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Button>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </Grid>
```

above is design code and c# code is below

```
private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            lstDevice.ItemsSource = MainPage.user.dArray.ToList();            
            lstDevice.SelectionChanged += item_Select;
        }

        private void item_Select(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            int p = ((ListBox)sender).SelectedIndex;
        }
```

how to generate listbox item select event and get the number or some property to recognize which item is selected? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may suits you better:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Height="Auto">
            <ListBox x:Name="lstDevice">
                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <toolkit:WrapPanel/>                        
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate >
                            <Button x:Name="btnData" Click="OnButtonClick" Tag="{Binding Name}" >
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                    <Canvas 
                                            Width="175" 
                                            Height="175"/>                                            
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Width="175" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </Grid>

    private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        lstDevice.ItemsSource = MainPage.user.dArray.ToList();            
    }

    private void OnButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button b = (Button)sender;
        var nameInTag=b.Tag.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Now my dArray has information which I have given to lstDevice.ItemSource

in OnButtonClick method I want to recognize which element of dArray is got clicked. do you have any idea how to do that?

Comment: what is dArray? I would use lambda expression something like `var c = dArray.Where(x => x == nameInTag).Select(x => x).FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: actually I have a class Device of which dArray is one of array
e.g. Device[] dArray;
Device has information in string like name,id,serialno etc and I want to display it as button on screen and by clicking I want to get information of that device's name,id,serial no etc.

Comment: I mean for that How can I bind information of dArray[0],dArray[1] with respective buttons?

Comment: DataContext should handle that, set button's tag `Tag="{Binding ID}"` and OnClick event you have `var c = dArray.Where(x => x.ID.ToString() == nameInTag).Select(x => x).FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: Each button has a DataContext that is your bound object, so:    MyItem clickedItem = (sender as Button).DataContext as MyItem;
No need to use the tag if you need the entire object to handle the OnButtonClick call.

Answer (score 0):

```
Make change in your xaml and cs code like this:

 <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Height="Auto">
                <ListBox x:Name="lstDevice" SelectionChange="item_Select">
                    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <toolkit:WrapPanel/>                        
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate >
                            <StackPanel>
                                <Button x:Name="btnData" >
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                        <Canvas 
                                                Width="175" 
                                                Height="175"/>                                            
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Width="175" />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Button>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </Grid>


        private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                lstDevice.ItemsSource = MainPage.user.dArray.ToList();            

            }

            private void item_Select(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                var selctedItem  = lstDevice.SelectedItem as (Your list box's itmsource)
            }
```

Comment: Error : The member "SelectionChange" is not recognized or is not accessible.